# How would I delete an array of QCheckBoxes using a vector of pointers to each element?

Tags: c++, qt

In my current project, I have an array of QCheckBoxes that I create at run-time given the dimensions from the user. Every time the user clicks the 'Generate' button, the dimensions that they inputted are gathered, and an array of QCheckBoxes is created. It is done in the following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_generateBoxes_clicked()
{
    int x_dim = ui->xDim->value();
    int y_dim = ui->yDim->value();
    int z_dim = ui->zDim->value();

    for(int i = 0; i < x_dim; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < y_dim; ++j){
            checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox( ui->dim1 ));
            checkBoxVector.last()->setGeometry(i * 20, j * 20, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

checkBoxVector is a global array of pointers declared in another source file:

```
QVector<QCheckBox*> checkBoxVector;
```

My question is, how would I go through checkBoxVector to remove every QCheckBox? Since the previous dimensions of the array are local variables that are lost once the function returns, when it is re-called how would I know how many elements to remove?

If the user was to press the 'Generate' button twice there would be overlapping QCheckBoxes, so I need to wipe them all every time the function is called. (Also, nobody wants a memory leak!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First delete all the elements (QCheckBoxes) in the vector and then clear the vector:

```
qDeleteAll(checkBoxVector);
checkBoxVector.clear();
```

Because you are adding checkbox pointers to the vector, just clearing the vector doesn't delete the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the vector using the member function `clear()`, i.e

```
checkBoxVector.clear();
```

This will remove everything so you can fill it again. The dimensions don't matter because the elements are stored in "1d" and QVector knows how many there are.

Edit: I should read more carefully this will delete the pointers. What you want is to iterate over each pointer deleting the object it points to, i.e.

```
vector<QCheckBoxes*>::iterator itr = checkBoxVector.begin();
while(itr != checkBoxVector.end())
{
    delete *(*(itr));
    ++itr;
}
```

Comment: Note `itr` is dereferenced twice, once to get to the pointer and a second time to get to the `QCheckBox` object.

Comment: This gives me a lot of errors:
error: conversion from ‘QCheckBox**’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<QCheckBox*, std::allocator<QCheckBox*> >::iterator’ requested
and
error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘itr != checkBoxVector.QVector<T>::end [with T = QCheckBox*, T* = QCheckBox**]()’
and
error: type ‘class QCheckBox’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer

Comment: Yes sorry, I was being a muppet. You only need to dereference one (I think, again untested) because delete expects a pointer to the object, it then calls the objects destructor.

The other error is probably because I wrote vector not QVector, also I was assuming the notation was similar to std::vector, it may be slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `QVector < QSharedPointer<QCheckBox> >` Everything will be deleted automatically.

Adding will look something like this:

```
CheckBoxes.append(QSharedPointer<QCheckBox>(new QCheckBox()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove every QCheckBox?

```
foreach (QCheckBox *checkBox, checkBoxVector)
    delete checkBox;

//QVector::clear() // clear does not release objects
```

Comment: This solution causes the program to close unexpectedly if I call the function 2 or 3 times. I'm not sure why though

Comment: Anyway this release all QCheckBox(es) in QVector and checkBoxVector.clear() use for removing elements from vector and releases the memory used by the vector.